# Why is the allowRegexes keyword in pyinputplus allowing ABC in pyip.inputNum(allowRegexes=[r'(C)+'])?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Working through Automate the Boring Stuff, and can't see why `allowRegexes` keyword in `pyinputplus` doesn't seem to be working for me.

for example

```
>>> import pyinputplus as pyip
>>> pyip.inputNum('input: ', allowRegexes=[r'(C)+'])
input: AB
'AB' is not a number.
input: ABC
'ABC'
```

It seems as though as long as I input any string containing `C` it will be allowed. But it should be only `C` or `CCCC...` that should pass I think.

I can't see that anyone else had issues with this. Is this some issue with Python versions, or am I missing something and being a regular expression donut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is either within your assumption of how the parameter `allowRegexes` works, or in your regex. Though I guess it's probably the former.

The behavior is this: If the regex set in `allowRegexes` matches *any part* of the input, the whole string will be valid (respectively invalid, if used in `blockRegexes`). The regex does not need to match the *entire* input. Granted, that may not be completely clear from the wording in the [documentation](https://pyinputplus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but the examples listed in the [description of `pyinputplus.inputInt()`](https://pyinputplus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#pyinputplus.inputInt) illustrate this behavior.

Since `(C)+` will match any `C` in a string, any sequence that contains a `C` anywhere will pass validation, as you observed. If you wanted only sequences of `C` without spaces, like `C`, `CC`, `CCC`, etc., to be added as valid input, your regex could e.g. look like this: `^C+$`. See https://regex101.com/r/x03Fes/1

```
>>> import pyinputplus as pyip
>>> pyip.inputNum('input: ', allowRegexes=[r'^C+$'])
input: ABC
'ABC' is not a number.
input: ACB
'ACB' is not a number.
input: CAB
'CAB' is not a number.
input: CAC
'CAC' is not a number.
input: CCC CCC
'CCC CCC' is not a number.
input: CCC
'CCC'
```