# pyinputplus allowRegexes keyword allows any input

Tags: python, regex, string, validation, input

I am trying to use `pyinputplus` to validate some inputs for storing flight arrangements.
In particular I am having issues with the `allowRegexes` keyword.

Here is my code (python 3.8.5):

```
>>> import pyinputplus as pyip
>>> confirmation_number = pyip.inputStr(
...             prompt='Confirmation number = ',
...             allowRegexes=[r'\w{6}']
...              ).upper()
Confirmation number = #$%}|+_
>>> name = pyip.inputStr(
...             prompt='Reservation name = ',
...             allowRegexes=[r'([A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+)']
...             ).title()
Reservation name = F1rstn@me La$tnam3
>>> confirmation_number
'#$%}|+_'
>>> name
'F1Rstn@Me La$Tnam3'
```

I would have expected that both of these inputs would have been blocked. Apparently, both will allow any input.

The docs only explain that `allowRegexes` will override `blockRegexes`, and any examples online I've found provide examples of regex and phone numbers, but not what is/isn't blocked accordingly.

Possible duplicate of [Why is the allowRegexes keyword in pyinputplus allowing ABC in pyip.inputNum(allowRegexes=[r'(C)+'])?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65878147/why-is-the-allowregexes-keyword-in-pyinputplus-allowing-abc-in-pyip-inputnumal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your understanding of the `allowRegexes` parameter is not entirely accurate. Although it is partially related, your question is not a duplicate of [Why is the allowRegexes keyword in pyinputplus allowing ABC in pyip.inputNum(allowRegexes=[r'(C)+'])?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65878147/why-is-the-allowregexes-keyword-in-pyinputplus-allowing-abc-in-pyip-inputnumal). In fact, there are two different misconceptions in your two function calls.

1. You seem to expect that *only* inputs that match the regex in `allowRegexes` will pass validation. But in fact, the behavior is that inputs for which the regex in `allowRegexes` matches will be valid *in addition* to those, that are *already* found valid by the respective function that is used.

   In your case, that is the function [`pyinputplus.inputStr()`](https://pyinputplus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#pyinputplus.inputStr), which accepts any string as input. So your first function call says "*Accept any input and additionally any input that contains a sequence of any six consecutive word characters*'. Clearly, the second part is redundant, so this is why you observe the described behavior.

   To remedy this, you have several options:

   **(a) Use a combination of `blockRegexes` and `allowRegexes`:**

   As you correctly wrote, `allowRegexes` will override `blockRegexes`. So you can use that to your advantage by first blocking any input using the regex `.*` and then allowing only the input that you want:

   ```
   >>> confirmation_number = pyip.inputStr(
   ...             prompt='Confirmation number = ',
   ...             blockRegexes=[r'.*'],
   ...             allowRegexes=[r'\w{6}']
   ...            ).upper()
   Confirmation number = #$%}|+_
   This response is invalid.
   ```

   **(b) Use `pyinputplus.inputRegex()` instead**

   There is a function that directly does what you expected. It is [`pyinputplus.inputRegex()`](https://pyinputplus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#pyinputplus.inputRegex):

   > Prompt the user to enter a string that matches the provided regex string (or regex object) and flags. Returns the entered string

   ```
   >>> confirmation_number = pyip.inputRegex(r'\w{6}',
   ...             prompt='Confirmation number = '
   ...            ).upper()
   Confirmation number = #$%}|+_
   '#$%}|+_' does not match the specified pattern.
   Confirmation number = 123.45
   '123.45' does not match the specified pattern.
   Confirmation number = abcde
   'abcde' does not match the specified pattern.
   Confirmation number = abCD_E
   >>>
   ```

   This takes care of your first problem.
2. If you attempt the same solution outlined above for your second example, the string will still be accepted. The reason for that is that the behavior of `allowRegexes` is actually different than you expected in a second way: The regex does not need to match the *entire* input. Instead, if the regex set in `allowRegexes` matches *any part* of the input, the whole string will be valid (respectively invalid, if used in `blockRegexes`).

   Let me explain using your example `F1rstn@me La$tnam3`: The regex that you used is `([A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+)`. While this does not match the *complete* string `F1rstn@me La$tnam3`, it *partially* matches the middle part `me La`. Therefore, the *whole* input is accepted as being valid. This also leads to the first example above accepting any and all strings that have a 6 word character sequence somewhere in them.

   To remedy this, tune your regexes so that they accept only *exactly* the sequence you want to allow. In your case, this is easily achieved by wrapping the regexes in `^` (asserts position at start of a line) and `$` (asserts position at end of a line):

   ```
   >>> confirmation_number = pyip.inputRegex(r'^\w{6}$',
   ...              prompt='Confirmation number = ',
   ...     ).upper()
   Confirmation number = #$%}|+_
   '#$%}|+_' does not match the specified pattern.
   Confirmation number = 123.45
   '123.45' does not match the specified pattern.
   Confirmation number = abcde
   'abcde' does not match the specified pattern.
   Confirmation number = 1234567890
   '1234567890' does not match the specified pattern.
   Confirmation number = abcdefghij
   'abcdefghij' does not match the specified pattern.
   Confirmation number = a2cD_e
   >>>
   ```

   See https://regex101.com/r/I5OU0L/1

   ```
    >>> name = pyip.inputRegex(r'^([A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+)$',
    ...     prompt='Reservation name = '
    ...     ).title()
    Reservation name = F1Rstn@Me La$Tnam3
    'F1Rstn@Me La$Tnam3' does not match the specified pattern.
    Reservation name = F1Rstn@Me Lastname
    'F1Rstn@Me Lastname' does not match the specified pattern.
    Reservation name = Firstnaem La$Tnam3
    'Firstnaem La$Tnam3' does not match the specified pattern.
    Reservation name = Firstname Lastname
    >>>
   ```

   See https://regex101.com/r/hDh40k/1

   This second issue is actually the same as the one in the issue you linked in your question as possible duplicate...

Comment: Solved. I had started to consider that allowRegexes might accept OTHER inputs but I convinced myself that didn't make any sense. Thank you so much for the thorough explanation.